# First order differential equations, homogeneous or linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation

$$\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{2x}{t} = \frac{1}{t^2(1+t^2)}$$

which I tried to solve by multiplying everything by $I(t)$ to solve linear equations where 
$$I(t) = e^{\int{P(t)}dt}$$

which resulted in 
$$2t \frac{dx}{dt} + 4x = \frac{2}{t(1+t^2)}$$

So I tried solving it with the homogeneous technique where $u = \frac{x}{t}$

which resulted in a stunning

$$t\frac{du}{dt} + 2u = \frac{1}{t(1+t^2)}$$
AKA the same thing as what I started with.

I'm not looking for an answer, could someone give me a subtle nudge in the right direction? Or fix my definitions of classifying and ODE

Comment: The ODE is linear but non-homogeneous due to the term on the right side. So you cant use the solving method for homogeneous ODEs. First solve the associated homogeneous ODE that is the ODE without the term on the right) . Second solve the non-homogeneous ODE for example thanks to the method of variation of parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{\int P(t)dt}$ is $t^{2}$ not $2t$. After multiplying by this the equation becomes $\frac d {dt} (t^{2}x(t))=\frac 1 {1+t^{2}}$. Integrating this we get $t^{2}x(t)=\arctan t+C$ so $x(t)=t^{-2}(\arctan t+C)$